# The named parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined

Tags: android, flutter

i have this error  The named parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onSelectNotification'. and i don't understand

below is my code

[image: 1]

i tried to upgrade pub , upgrade flutter_local_notification ,
i even changed onSelectNotification to onDidReceiveNotificationResponse
but nothing,
i am still learning flutter , how can i solve this please

Comment: add the code in written form instead of screenshots

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In version 10 the following callback has been reworked [flutter_local_notifications changelog 10.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog#1000)

For using **`onSelectNotification`** callback **use** **flutter_local_notifications** **below 10.0.0.**
This callback (`onSelectNotification`) is guaranteed to work in version 9.3.1.

Also, in version 10.0.0 and higher, the following callback can be used instead:

`onDidReceiveNotificationResponse`:
invoked only when the app is running. This works when a user has selected a notification or notification action. This replaces the onSelectNotification

`onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse`: invoked on a background isolate when a user has selected a notification action. This replaces the onSelectNotificationAction callback